# Explanation of Monad laws in F#

Tags: f#, monads

Here is [Explanation of Monad laws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433608/explanation-of-monad-laws) in Haskell.

How do explain  Monad laws in F#?

1. bind (M, return) is equivalent to M.
2. bind ((return x), f) is equivalent to f x.
3. bind (bind (m, f),g) is equivalent to bind(m, (fun x -> bind (f x, g))).

Comment: Why does this require an explanation? Where's the hard part?

Comment: `bind (M, return)` isn't exactly `M`, remember that F# is impure so the binding could cause side effects and mutation.

Comment: @RamonSnir bind is not meant to be the mutating part. It merely organizes side effects in a partial order.

Comment: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/cb9942ff7fb7f8a463070cc1c216b0170c399e28/tests/FSharpx.Tests/MaybeTest.fs#L49-L62

Comment: @SassaNF F# is impure, which means you could conceivably have some side effect in your implementation of `bind` -- that is, a side effect other than the one you're handling via the monad. There are **very few** good reasons to implement such a thing. Ramon's point is that, unlike Haskell, the F# type system can't stop you from implementing an arbitrary side effect in your `bind`; if you did, the monad laws wouldn't quite hold.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that a good way to understand them in F# is to look at what they mean using the computation expression syntax. I'll write `m` for some computation builder, but you can imagine that this is `async` or any other computation type.

**Left identity**

```
m { let! x' = m { return x }   =   m { let x' = x
    return! f x' }                     return! f x' }
```

**Right identity**

```
m { let! x = comp              =   m { return! comp }
    return x }
```

**Associativity**

```
m { let! x = comp              =   m { let! y = m { let! x = comp
    let! y = f x                                    return! f x }
    return! g y }                      return! g y }
```

The laws essentially tell you that you should be able to refactor one version of the program to the other without changing the meaning - just like you can refactor ordinary F# programs.

Comment: The Associativity example is a bit confusing: what happened to `g` in the right code example? Should the last line be `return! g y`?

Comment: @ChristopherStevenson It took me only 4.5 years to fix that typo!